# Interfaces and restraints

Tags: c#, interface

Considering the following setup, how can I restrain `IConnection` to only contain `IPort` of the same `ConnectionType` in `Ports`? Maybe I am overlooking something obvious here:

```
Enum ConnectionType
{
    Undefined,
    Type1,
    Type2
}


IConnection
{
    ConnectionType ConnectionType {get;set}
    IEnumerable<IPort> Ports {get;set;}
}

IPort
{
    ConnectionType ConnectionType {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: WHat's the need for the duplicated information? if all Ports need the same connection type why not only keep it once for the entire collection of ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot enforce such constraints at compile time.

You will have to do some checking at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

In order to control the type of `IPorts`, you will need to change the class to not expose the list in a writeable manner.

Make the property read-only, returning a new `ReadOnlyCollection` to prevent adding any type of `IPort` to the internal collection. Add an `AddPort` method that will only allow adding an `IPort` of the right type.

Comment: Actually I am doing that already in a way, the code in the question is just a dummy to show the problem. I was just thinking, if it would be possible to force the type check into the interface.

Answer (score 2):

How about wrapping up the enum and using generics?

```
    public interface IConnectionType
{
    ConnectionTypeEnum Connection{ get; set;}
}

public enum ConnectionTypeEnum
{
   Undefined,
   Type1,
   Type2
}

public interface IPort<T> where T : IConnectionType
{
}

public interface IConnection<T> where T : IConnectionType
{
    IEnumerable<IPort<T>> Ports {get;set;}
}
```

I'm not sure if there's any point in having the enum anymore though

Comment: While this is a viable answer for the simple example in my question, it will not work, if I try to put further restrains in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the connection type in the IPort interface, have a property of IConnection, e.g.

```
IConnection
{
  ConnectionType ConnectionType { get; }
  IEnumerable<IPort> Ports { get; }
}

IPort
{
  IConnection Connection { get; }
}
```

Management of these properties should be left to the implementation.

Comment: Would that simply create a similar problem. Making sure that the connection pointed to by all ports is the connection the port belongs to?

Comment: I guess, but it does enforce that the ConnectionType that the IPort instance can connect to is the same ConnectionType that the IConnection interface is set to.